# How can I find similar item in Set using binary Search?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I have `Set<Info> info = new TreeSet<>()` and the set is ordered based on the age 
where `class Info { String name;int age}`

I am wondering how can I use binary search and find the position of the item which is highest but smaller then specified age . I know how can I do it in case of list but I am not sure in case of Set

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring `info` as a [`Set<Info>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html), you can use a [`NavigableSet<Info>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) (as [`TreeSet<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) implements `NavigableSet<E>`). Then, you can invoke [`NavigableSet#lower`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html#lower(E)) with your specified `Info` object. The documentation of this method states:

> Returns the greatest element in this set strictly less than the given element, or null if there is no such element.

This will perform a binary search internally, which can be more efficient than a linear search when your `NavigableSet<Info>` is large.

Comment: @ArturA What does your `Info#compareTo` method look like? Could you post it in your question?

Comment: Ignore what I said in the comment, but. I am  wondering what if If I want to find the position of the element. what is the optimal way of doing it.

Comment: @ArturA Elements in a `Set` don't have a "position", _perse_. Even when it comes to a `SortedSet` / `NavigableSet` elements only have a position relative to other elements; they don't really have an _absolute_ position such as an index in the context of a `List`.

Comment: @ArturA To elaborate on what @Slaw mentioned, you can get the element’s relative position with the size of `NavigableSet#headSet`, but that value doesn’t mean much.